# I don't see the difference shading made in this marble

Tags: shaders

In the Donut tutorial, v4, [Part 5 on Shading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsLO1F5x7yM&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEPv5y--4MKpciLaoQYZB1Z), the main thing is working in the Shading Workspace with the Shader Editor to make a [PBR shader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physically_based_rendering) (Andrew, the instructor, calls it that at *t* = 13:26) for a marble countertop using data provided by a set of files downloaded from Andrew's website, [Poliigon](https://www.Poliigon.com). It's an interesting process.

As we go through it, Andrew talks about improvements in the properties of the marble caused by various steps along the way. However, I don't see what he means.

Here is a side-by-side comparison of the marble with and without the PBR shader at the maximum magnification Blender would give me:
[image]

I don't see the difference.

Here is Blender at the two stages from which the above images were made:
[image]
and
[image]

Are my eyes insufficiently trained to pick out subtle differences in those images, or have I done something wrong in building the shader, or is there some other problem here?

Comment: The set-up looks OK, a couple of thoughts.. 1. make sure your plane is the right way up (Header > Overlays > Face Orientation in Solid mode should show blue) 2. Rotate the plane to have a look at it under a raking light.. play with the Strength setting in the _Normal Map_ node. Temporarily ram the Metallic' to 1 and your Roughness to 0 in your plane, to see what it looks like on a perfect mirror.

Comment: Actually with this specific texture set it is hard to see, because it is a very polished surface and very smooth. There are only a few tiny spots over the whole texture where you can see some surface imperfections, hardly visible when you are not close. So maybe not the best example Andrew chose there. However, on his homepage you'll find older tutorials on making realistic materials, or how the at that time new _Principled BSDF_ works. A little outdated, some nodes and functions are different now, but the basics like why use normal maps or bump maps still apply today.

Comment: *"Are my eyes insufficiently trained to pick out subtle differences in those images"* - perhaps it would be more visible if there was a strong point light shining on it from a side. Or HDRI.